# Remove empty field's name from document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been able to add a large volume of empty keys in a MongoDB collection. As empty keys is not allowed in MongoDB I'm having a hard time to unset the key using regular methods in MongoDB. Is there a workaround for this kind of problems using mongo shell?

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "": "I should not exist, I have no key..."
}
```

Comment: How many fields do you have in each document?

Comment: Around 20 fields in each document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can delete the empty string field using bulk operations.

We need to iterate over the cursor snapshot then use the [`bulkWrite`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite) method method to bulk update the document. Note that we need to replace the document because we can't [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset) the empty field or rename it. So  an update operation is not possible here.

```
let requests = [];
db.coll.find( { "": { "$exists": true } } ).snapshot().forEach( document => { 
    delete document[""];  
    requests.push( { 
        "replaceOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": document._id }, 
            "replacement": document 
        }
    }); 

    if ( requests.length === 1000 ) {
        // Execute per 1000 operations and re-init
        db.coll.bulkWrite(requests);
        requests = [];
    }
});

// Clean up queues
if ( requests.length > 0 ) {
    db.coll.bulkWrite(requests);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a throw....

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    delete doc[''];
    db.collection.save(doc);
});
```

There are some abilities to manage documents that have errors in them, such as empty keys.

Comment: Don't do this!! It's bad for performance. They are far better ways to "unset" the field.

Comment: Please provide a better solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Thx for the idea. This triggers error in my MongoDB shell version: 3.2.5 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ] after element list :

Answer (score 1):

If you are on version 5.0 or later, you can use [`$setField` expression](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/reference/operator/aggregation/setField/) with expressive pipeline update:

```
db.c.updateMany({ "": { "$exists": true } },
      [ {$replaceWith:{$setField:{field:"",input:"$$ROOT",value:"$$REMOVE"}}}]
)
```

If you are on 4.2 through 4.4 (pre-5.0) you can do it with different pipeline update:

```
db.c.updateMany({ "": { "$exists": true } },
      [ {$replaceWith:{$arrayToObject:{$filter:{
             input:{$objectToArray:"$$ROOT"}, 
             cond:{$ne:["$$this.k",""]}
      }}}}]
)
```